# AcquireTokenSilentAsync not working for accessing web api registered in azure AD

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory

I am trying to get access token for a web api which is registered in Azure AD. I am calling the AcquireTokenSilentAsync from the MVC action method as below

```
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetWeatherReport()
        {
            string token = await GetAccessTokenForAPIAsync();
            // some code
        }

 private async Task<string> GetAccessTokenForAPIAsync()
        {
            string authority = _authOptions.Authority;

            var cache = _tokenCacheFactory.CreateForUser(User);

            var authContext = new AuthenticationContext(authority,cache);

            string clientId = _authOptions.ClientId;
            string clientSecret = _authOptions.ClientSecret;
            var credential = new ClientCredential(clientId, clientSecret);
            var userId = User.GetObjectId();

            var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenSilentAsync(
                resourceId, // web api app id
                credential
                ,
                new UserIdentifier(userId, UserIdentifierType.UniqueId)
                );

            return result.AccessToken;
        }
```

When I am running the application and try to run the GetWeatherReport action method and debugged, it is calling AcquireTokenSilentAsync and then the debugger is going back to GetWeatherReport action method and this process is keep on repeating

I can able to get access token for web api from AcquireTokenAsync as below

```
var result = await authContext.AcquireTokenAsync(
                resourceId,
                credential)
```

but I want to try with AcquireTokenSilentAsync.

Where I am doing wrong? If you want any other information, please let me know.

Comment: Try use fiddler to trace which is the problem for token request .

Comment: I have tried but not getting anything. its keep on calling GetWeatherReport action method and AcquireTokenSilentAsync.

Comment: AcquireTokenSilentAsync is throwing exception and we shuould acquire token from AcquireTokenAsync.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot get a brand-new access token for a user with `AcquireTokenSilentAsync`. It is used to acquire a new token with a cached token. Actually, the cached refresh token will be used in the flow.

For more details, you may refer to: [AcquireTokenSilentAsync using a cached token](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/AcquireTokenSilentAsync-using-a-cached-token) and [Recommended pattern to acquire a token](https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-library-for-dotnet/wiki/AcquireTokenSilentAsync-using-a-cached-token)

---

If it is not the root cause, you may set a break point at `return result.AccessToken;`, and then analyze the token in [jwt.io](https://jwt.io/) to see if all the claims were correct.

---

**Update**

Based on your description, I think you may want to use [OAuth 2.0 On-Behalf-Of flow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow)

[image]

Your MVC application should equal to Web API A in the picture. And the web API you want to call should equal to the Web API B in the picture.

If so, you may refer to the official sample: [active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/active-directory-dotnet-webapi-onbehalfof/blob/master/TodoListService/Controllers/TodoListController.cs)

Check the `private static async Task<UserProfile> CallGraphAPIOnBehalfOfUser()` method. It follows the following steps:

1. Get user token from current http context. 
2. Constructor user assertion with that token. 
3. Acquire a new token with user assertion for target Web API.
4. Call the Web API with new token.

I think this would meet your requirement. In this way, user only needs to login to your MVC application. Your MVC application itself will obtain a new token for target API.

> Note: Admin must grant consent firstly for these apps in Azure AD. You
> can get details in [Register the application and service in Azure
> AD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow#register-the-application-and-service-in-azure-ad)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. AcquireTokenSilentAsync throwing exception and it is handled by AcquireTokenAsync. But why AcquireTokenSilentAsync throwing error?? There is userassertion or usercredentials parameter in those methods. Will it be used for user level permission? like if user info passed and if user does not have permission the azure ad response with 401?

Comment: Actually, there is no enough user assertion or credentials in your posted code. There is only a user ID. The user ID will be used to find if there is any existing cached token for the user. If there is one and it is not expired,it will be directly return back. Or if the refresh token is not expired, it will acquire a new token with the refresh token, and then return it back.  If not the above two cases, then exception will be thrown, at this time, you need to use `AcquireTokenAsync` to acquire the token first.

Comment: Find a pattern which meets your requirement. You may check my update.

Comment: Thanks for taking time and explaining the steps. I will try this one.